# Problem upgrading Spring Boot from 2.1.5 to 2.1.6, does not appear to be removing data correctly/in the right order

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to upgrade Spring Boot from 2.1.5 to 2.1.6 (the point is to move to 2.2x but this is where I found the problem)

I get the following exception when trying to remove an entity of the type subjectType in one of our tests:

```
  Detail: Key (id)=(5cd21b13-5dea-4384-9589-3a4d1ab4dfea) is still referenced from table "metric".
```

That seems clear enough right? I am trying to remove something that still has a reference to it.

However, the code always used to work. And it is as simple as this:

```
List<Metric> metrics = metricRepo.findBySubjectTypeId(id);
metricRepo.deleteAll(metrics);
subjectTypeRepo.delete(subjectType);
entityManager.flush();
... //some code that removes data from other systems now that this part succeeded
```

The exception happens on the flush and the id is the id of the subjectType that is being deleted.

Metric has a fairly standard reference to subjectType as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Metric {

    @JoinColumn(name = "subject_type_id", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_subject_type"))
    @ManyToOne
    private SubjectType subjectType;
}
```

We don't use cascade deletes because of data in other systems that need to be removed. However, manually deleting the objects that refer to subjectType before actually removing subjectType itself should work in simple non-concurrent cases.

I've tried to look at the changes in dependencies between 2.1.5 and 2.1.6 but couldn't pick out any obvious candidates, and Hibernate didn't seem to get upgraded except for the validator. So I'm really at a loss what suddenly changed here and what is causing this issue. The issue is still present in the (currently latest) 2.2.1 release as well.

Comment: hey man, did you manage to resolve this issue? We're upgrading from 2.1.5 to 2.1.6 and the dekete() methods are all broken

Comment: @Brunaldo we just settled on deleting things with the entityManager itself instead of the repository delete/deleteAll methods. Too much automagic going on here.